# Using Native Navigation + Compose TopAppBar is good idea?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation

I am using Fragment + Compose with Native Navigation (nav_graph.xml) in my project.

Using TopAppBar like:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SampleScreen(
    title: String,
    navController: NavController
) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = title) },
                navigationIcon = { IconButton(onClick = { navController.popBackStack() }) { icon() } }
            )
        }
    ) { /* content */ }
}
```

`navController` is coming from Fragment's `findNavController()` method.

```kotlin
class SampleFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                AppTheme {
                    SampleScreen(navController = findNavController())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a good approach for using TopAppBar ?

Am I missing the navigation-related features of the XML TopAppBar?

Should I use such navigation-related components like TopAppBar as XML?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if it is working **fine** for you (i.e. without bugs, and you can add features easily, and do refactoring and maintenance easily), then continue using the previous navigation components with compose; a lot of people do that; in fact, since the new compose navigation has some drawbacks.

Alternatively, some folks recommend exclusively utilizing Compose components rather than combining them with XML components. This approach ensures that you can fully leverage Compose's advantages, namely, its ease of use and flexibility. Therefore, it is advisable to integrate Compose components like TopAppBar into your project.